# Attribute based validation and ErrorMessage

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-annotations

I researched about validation tehniques on net and found this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat

Does anyone know why validation is not happening if you remove ErrorMessage="" from the attribute?

this works

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="error message")]
```

this doesn't

```
[Required()]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always retrieve error message with [ValidationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.formaterrormessage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method because it has fallback mechanism to use default value if direct message through ErrorMessage property is not specified or if resource based error message is not specified.

Comment: I am doing that in my custom attributes. The problem is that if ErrorMessage is not specified when adding attribute to property, it will not show any validation error on UI when bound to simple controls, like TextBox, but it will show correctly when binding to list controls (ex GridView). And binding in both cases occurs on same data. HOwever, if I specify error message, then TextBox picks up validation error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the attribute-based validation, but I think it's because the IDataErrorInfo interface expects a string to be passed in:

```
public string this[string propertyName]{}
```

Comment: @Goran  If the Required attribute uses the  IDataErrorInfo interface(I don't know if it does), then it has everything to do with your question.

Comment: I have provided a link for an article, there you can see how it is implemented/

Comment: The IDataErrorInfo is working fine, if I do validation in code, then its working as expected, if I use attributes without ErrorMessage, then it doesn't. I am wondering why.

Comment: @Goran  I'm thinking that the validation attributes actually implement the IDataErrorInfo and, as a result, you need to include an ErrorMessage string in your annotation for it to work.  Of course, I can be way off on this.